# Numpy sum (Numpy 1.15.4, linked with MKL)

Tags: python, numpy, intel-mkl

I am running the latest version of Python/Numpy(1.15.4) from Anaconda, linked with the MKL. I use the following epsilon:

```
epsilon = 2**(-53)
```

So that 1.0 + epsilon is equal to 1.0. Then I define the following numpy array which is filled with epsilon except the first 8 elements which are equal to one.

```
import numpy as np
n = 1000000
a = np.full(n, epsilon)
a[0:8] = 1.0
```

If you compute the sum of the array with a classical reduction from left to right, you should get exactly 8.0 as all the epsilon do not change the reduction as it goes on. But I am surprised to see that

```
print(np.sum(a))
```

gives you back 8.000000000111008 which is not what I expected. I have tried to put the ones in the middle and a the end of the array to check if the sum is not done backward, but nothing changes. Any idea on how the sum is done?

PS: I am well aware of the fact that floating point arithmetic is tricky and + is non-associative with floating points which makes the results of reduction dependent of the order of summation. But I cannot find out which summation order is used here.

Comment: I am aware that floating point arithmetic is tricky, but 1.0 + epsilon should be equal to 1.0, and 8.0 + epsilon should also be equal to one, even with floating point arithmetic

Comment: Ok, I see your point now. `1 + epsilon == 1` is `True` but setting `epsilon = 0` does drop out `8` as the answer

Comment: Random remark: numpy's sum is not doing naive summation (but also not as expensive as [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)). But i don't have a link right now. **edit** Ah, it's [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation).

Comment: @sascha: It gets very close to what I am looking for. I would like to know what Numpy is doing here.

Comment: Ok. It is a divide and conquer summation. If you have a link that shows that numpy is doing this, I will accept it as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The wiki-entry above says it's numpy's default and links to [this merge-request adding it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685). But there seems to be some traction in regards to this topic (current work...) so i won't follow all those paths to reason about the current state / adding an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, `numpy` uses pairwise summation. So the summation will (roughly) look like this at the end of a recursive pairwise summation when the call stack starts to resolve:

```
(1+1) + (1+1) + (1+1) + (1+1) + (epsilon + epsilon) + ... + (epsilon + epsilon)
(2+2) + (2+2) + (2*epsilon) + (2*epsilon) + ... + (2*epsilon)
(4+4) + (4*epsilon) + (4*epsilon) + ... + (4*epsilon)
8 + (8*epsilon) + (8*epsilon) + ... + (8*epsilon)
8 + (16*epsilon) + (16*epsilon) + ... + (16*epsilon)
...
8 + (999992*epsilon)
```

You're correct in stating that `1.0 + epsilon` is equal to `1.0`. It's tempting to think that `x + epsilon == x` for all `x`. It does hold when `x` is "large", however, this *doesn't* hold when `x == epsilon` (i.e. `epsilon + epsilon != epsilon`). Thus `epsilon + epsilon` terms will start to pile up:

```
In [27]: epsilon = 2**(-53)

In [28]: 1.0 + epsilon == 1.0
Out[28]: True

In [29]: 2.0 + epsilon == 2.0
Out[29]: True

In [30]: epsilon + epsilon == epsilon
Out[30]: False

In [31]: epsilon
Out[31]: 1.1102230246251565e-16

In [32]: epsilon + epsilon
Out[32]: 2.220446049250313e-16

In [33]: 123*epsilon
Out[33]: 1.3655743202889425e-14
```

I can't quite get `numpy`s answer, but we can get very close:

```
In [36]: 8 + (999992*epsilon)
Out[36]: 8.000000000111022

In [62]: def pairwise_sum(arr):
    ...:   if len(arr) <= 2:
    ...:     return sum(arr)
    ...:   midpoint = len(arr)//2
    ...:   first_half = arr[:midpoint]
    ...:   second_half = arr[midpoint:]
    ...:   return pairwise_sum(first_half) + pairwise_sum(second_half)
    ...:

In [63]: pairwise_sum(a)
Out[63]: 8.0000000001110205
```

So there's clearly some *other* difference here (some implementation detail), but hopefully this convinces you that `numpy` is in fact using pairwise summation.

HTH.